# Getting SAXException while using document.parse(string)

Tags: java, android, document, inputstream

I want to reuse the Inputstream coming from HTTP response.resultset()...

- I converted inputstream to byte[] array (also need to store so I create byte array.)
- Than convert into string
- when i pass it to document.parse(string) gave error saxparserException:---eof not found
- **working fine with document.parse(stream)**.

//------------Following methods are not helpfull for me ,each of them leads to
saxparserException protocl not found .

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;    

public static String readInputStreamAsString(InputStream in) 
    throws IOException {

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result = bis.read();
    while(result != -1) {
      byte b = (byte)result;
      buf.write(b);
      result = bis.read();
    }        
    return buf.toString();
}



//--------------


byte[] bytes=new byte[inputStream.available()];
inputStream.read(bytes);
String s = new String(bytes);

//------------------

  StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
  int value = 0;
  boolean active = true;
  while (active) {
        value = is.read();
        if (value == -1) {
            throw new IOException("End of Stream");
        } else if (value != '\n') {
            response.append((char) value);
            continue;
        } else {
            active = false;
        }
    }
    return response.toString();

//--------------

 BufferedInputStream ib = new BufferedInputStream(is,1024*1024);
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 String temp = ib.readLine();
 while (temp !=null){
     sb.append (temp);
     sb.append ("\n");
     temp = ib.readLine();
    }
 s = sb.toString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue  by using:-

document.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream))

Answer (score 0):

If you got http response which includes xml data, you can parse xml data using [saxparser](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example).

Comment: Thanks for your response,but I want to solve the issue why this thing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have misunderstood the `SAXParser.parse` method signature.

The versions of the parse method that take a String argument expect that String to represent a URI referring to the content and not the content itself.

If you've saved your input in a String variable, you're best off opening a StringReader on the string, basing an InputSource on the StringReader, and passing that to the parser.

Comment: Thanks for your response
 when i tried to print the string it is same as I accepted but when I parse it gives error,when I reconvert into inputstream it again gives the error.
I want to solve the issue why this thing occurs.
I read a blog with same issue in that they said use string buffer to convert the stream not string reader.